# AFJSONRequestOperation error in xcode/iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, afnetworking

I am following a tutorial (http://bit.ly/NI9kQe) on how to allow iOS to communicate with a web server and it uses AFNetworking.  The following code is throwing errors in xcode (see after code):

```
#pragma mark - init
//intialize the API class with the destination host name

-(API*)init
{
//call super init
self = [super init];

if (self != nil) {
    //initialize the object
    user = nil;

    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

    // Accept HTTP Header; see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
  }

return self;
}
```

The 2 Errors I get are:

1) Unknown Receiver AFJSONRequestOperation

2) No visible @interface declares the selector setDefaultHeader:Value

I am using xcode 5.0 and building for iOS7.

Thanks,

Comment: Import the correct header.

Comment: The AFNetworking.h? It has been imported.

Comment: What version of AFNetworking are you trying to use?

Comment: The latest on GitHub (http://bit.ly/t5FGz2)

Comment: I didn't read that tutorial, but those methods you are using (registerHTTPOperationClass:, setDefaultHeader:value) are part of the AFHTTPClient class, which does not exist anymore in AFNetworking 2.0. The replacement, providing similar functionality with a similar interface(but not the same) is AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.